# Angular 1.4: Disable button after click

Tags: angularjs

I have a situation where I want to disable the button for a few seconds when clicked. Here is the code for button:

```
<button uib-popover="Create TO" popover-trigger="mouseenter" data-ng-click="createTransportOrder(item.confirmed_price_id)" data-ng-disabled="item.transport_order_id || !item.confirmed_price_id" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
                            <i class="fa fa-truck"></i>
                        </button>
```

And here is the `createTransportOrder` method:

```
$scope.createTransportOrder = function (priceResponseId) {
            var priceResponseIds = [priceResponseId];
            PriceRequestsModel.createTransportOrdersByIds(priceResponseIds).then(
                function (response) {
                    $scope.messages = response.messages;
                    updateSelectedPriceRequests();
                    getPriceRequests();
                },
                function (response) {
                    $scope.messages = response.messages;
                }
            )
        };
```

I have tried a couple of things but in vain. How can I do this?

Comment: for how much time you want it disabled?

Comment: for just three seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can add `setTimeout` at the end of `createTransportOrder`

```
 this.button.nativeElement.disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
      this.button.nativeElement.disabled = false;
    },5000);
```

Add `#mybutton` to your button `<button (click)="yourclick()" #mybutton>Your button</button>`

add variable `@ViewChild('mybutton') button;` to your component

Stackbliz demo code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-disable-5second

With angular 1.4 you can change to

Set an id to your button as `<button id="mybutton">`

Add these code to below of `click` function.

```
document.getElementById('mybutton').disabled = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById('mybutton').disabled = false;
    },5000);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. My angular version is 1.4 and the answer you gave probably isn't for my version. I have updated the heading of the question.

Comment: This works fine but my problem is that I have to list data where every row contains that one button I want to disable after click. So `id` wont work. Neither would `class` as it'll pick the first occurrence of the button. is there anyway I can get the current button in the `createTransportOrder` method?